# Why would I use auto-implementation over encapsulation?

Tags: c#, private, encapsulation, public

```
private int someInt;

public int GetSomeInt()
{
    return someInt;
}
```

When would I use the above code over the below code?

```
public int SomeInt { get; set; }
```

I've been told to *always* encapsulate *all* variables rather than declaring them as public, and auto-implementation seems to be doing just that.

Doesn't this nullify the purpose of encapsulation as the field is declared public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When would I use the above code over the below code?

When you are paid by the parenthesis?  :-)

Remember that the code

```
public int SomeInt { get; set; }
```

is shorthand for the equivalent of

```
private int someInt;

public int SomeInt
{
   get { return someInt; }
   set { someInt = value; }
}
```

So any logic you could imagine putting in your `GetSomeInt` method can also be put in the 'getter' (or 'setter') for the `SomeInt` property.

Where possible, you should use the `public int SomeInt { get; set; }` syntax since it immediately alerts the reader that what you have is a simple property that can be set or accessed without any further logic to be understood.

Where the get or set logic is more complex the longer form of the property definition can be used.

Notwithstanding my facetious remark about parentheses, the Framework Design Guidelines for [Property Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property) suggest that

> If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method. Notice that this rule does not apply to indexers, where we do expect exceptions as a result of validating the arguments.

So that would be one example of a situation where you might implement `GetSomeInt` rather than a `SomeInt` property getter.

Answer (score 6):

Auto-implementation is just syntactic sugar for encapsulated fields for when no additional logic is required other than setting or retrieving the field value. It does not replace encapsulation, it's just there to save time and keystrokes. The backing field of an auto-implemented property cannot be accessed by your own code — all that's visible is the property. This property, and its accessors, can have any of the same access modifiers a field can have.

A more accurate auto-implemented equivalent of what you have, with a private backing field, contains a private setter:

```
public int SomeInt { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code is synthetic sugar kind of things.

```
public int MyValue { get; set; }
```

If you look at IL ( MSIL ) code generated after that you realize what compiler actually doing.

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication3.Sample
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private int32 '<MyValue>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance int32 get_MyValue () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x205c
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication3.Sample::'<MyValue>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method Sample::get_MyValue

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_MyValue (
            int32 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2064
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldarg.1
        IL_0002: stfld int32 ConsoleApplication3.Sample::'<MyValue>k__BackingField'
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Sample::set_MyValue

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2053
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Sample::.ctor

    // Properties
    .property instance int32 MyValue()
    {
        .get instance int32 ConsoleApplication3.Sample::get_MyValue()
        .set instance void ConsoleApplication3.Sample::set_MyValue(int32)
    }

} // end of class ConsoleApplication3.Sample
```

In above code compiler automatic generate private field.

```
.field private int32 '<MyValue>k__BackingField'
```

So still field is private and property is public. You can specify access modifier for get and set as well to control property access level.